# Invoke service when screen turns on (Android)

Tags: android, service, lockscreen

I am creating a lockscreen app with facial recognition. As a first step I am creating a simple lockscreen that unlocks on `Button` click. The lockscreen should start when `Switch` on `MainActivity` is turned on. I created a `Service` which starts my lockscreen activity, but the activity does not show again once I turn off and then turn on my screen.
I am a beginner in android and don't understand what to do. I would be happy if i could get some help.

The java files are:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.sanket.droidlockersimple;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Switch enableLocker;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        enableLocker = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.enableLocker);
        enableLocker.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(enableLocker.isChecked()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DroidLockerService.class);
                    startService(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

DroidLockerService.java

```
package com.sanket.droidlockersimple;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class DroidLockerService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, LockScreen.class);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

LockScreen.java

```
package com.sanket.droidlockersimple;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class LockScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button unlock;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock_screen);

        Button unlock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        unlock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/22601046/3895150

Comment: try checking out the source for the "Official Lock Screen" see-> stackoverflow.com/a/2141321/1815624

Comment: perhaps this might also help github.com/Joisar/LockScreenApp

Comment: also you will want to look into adding http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT to your manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what you need is a `BroadcastReceiver`

You have a service running, but something needs to tell the service that the screen has turned on or off.  Android accomplishes this by issuing broadcast events whenever certain things occur (i.e. phone call received, system turned on, etc).  Any registered broadcast receiver that has included the relevant `BroadcastIntent` will be informed that the event has occurred.

Your Broadcast Receiver can then tell your service that the event has occured and your service can respond appropriately.

I think that the particular broadcast events that you need to register for are "ACTION_SCREEN_ON" and "ACTION_SCREEN_OFF".  See the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) developer reference page for details.

Also read the [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) for intents and intent filters in Android, and here is the BroadcastReceiver reference page.  (StackOverflow won't let me post more than 2 links yet...just search for it on the Android developer website.)